# How to render random object from array in React?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

the problem is I have a component and an array with objects inside. I would like to choose a random object from the array and render it. Here is the code I already have:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const DATA = [
  {
    key1: 'value1',
    key2: ['string1', 'string2', 'string3']
  },
  {
    key1: 'value2',
    key2: ['string4', 'string5', 'string6']
  },
  {
    key1: 'value3',
    key2: ['string7', 'string8', 'string9']
  }
];

const MyComponent = () => {
  const [randomData, setRandomData] = useState({});

  const getRandomObject = (array) => {
    const randomObject = array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
    setRandomData(randomObject);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getRandomObject(DATA);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>{randomData.key1}</h2>
      {randomData.key2.map((item) => (
        <div>
          <input type='checkbox' id={item} value={item} />
          <label htmlFor={item}>{item}</label>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
 
export default MyComponent;
```

The browser throws me an error:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

Does anyone know what's wrong? Thanks in advance

Comment: use `const [randomData, setRandomData] = useState(DATA[0]);` for initial render.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `useEffect()` callback runs after the initial render (not before). So on the first render `randomData.key2` will be `undefined`, so you can't call `.map()` on it. You have a few options to fix this, but the most appropriate is to remove the `useEffect()` and set the data to a random value when you first call `useState()`:

```js
const getRandomObject = (array) => {
  const randomObject = array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
  return randomObject;
};

const MyComponent = () => {
  const [randomData, setRandomData] = useState(() => getRandomObject(DATA));

  return (
    ...
  );
}
```

See working example below:

```js
const { useState } = React;

const DATA = [
  {
    key1: 'value1',
    key2: ['string1', 'string2', 'string3']
  },
  {
    key1: 'value2',
    key2: ['string4', 'string5', 'string6']
  },
  {
    key1: 'value3',
    key2: ['string7', 'string8', 'string9']
  }
];

const getRandomObject = (array) => {
  const randomObject = array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
  return randomObject;
};

const MyComponent = () => {
  const [randomData, setRandomData] = useState(() => getRandomObject(DATA));

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>{randomData.key1}</h2>
      {randomData.key2.map((item) => (
        <div>
          <input type='checkbox' id={item} value={item} />
          <label htmlFor={item}>{item}</label>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
 
ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

If you pass a function to `useState()`, react will invoke that function the first time `useState()` is called (and not for subsequent rerenders) and set the state to the returned value, which will allow you to set your state to a random value for the intial render.

---

Another option to fix this would be to check that `randomData.key2` is defined before using `.map()` on it. You can do this by checking if `randomData.key2` has a value (ie: isn't `undefined`) before you call `.map()` on your array. You can do this with [optional chaining `(?.)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining):

```js
randomData.key2?.map(...)
```

The above checks that `randomData.key2` isn't `undefined` or `null` before `.map()` is invoked on it. You can think of this short-circuiting behaviour to be similar to the below code:

```js
randomData.key2 && randomData.key2.map(...)
```

This would also work, and was commonly used before optional chaining was introduced to the language. Out of all of these options, I would suggest the first for your case, but if you find that you need to use `useEffect()` (eg: you have some asynchronous code that obtains `DATA`), then one of the other options would work better for that case.